# PHP : How to remove string between "[" and "]"

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to remove string inside [...] including "[]" itself. I tried searching for a solution from this site. I have a clue that I should try something with preg_replace but it seems too expert to me.

For example :

```
[gallery ids="92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100" orderby="rand"] Description The thirty-two storey resort condominium in Phuket, located Just 150m from Patong beach where choices of activities, water sp
```

I need to remove **[gallery ids="92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100" orderby="rand"]** from the example text. And it always begins with **[gallery ids="** .

Please suggest.

Comment: Your question’s title is confusing: you don’t want the string *between* “[” and “]” removed, you want the string removed that starts with “[” and ends in “]” (including the brackets). I just accidentally downvoted a valid answer (now revoked) because I misunderstood…

Comment: @RaphaelSchweikert `inside [...] including "[]" itself`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
$string = '[gallery ids="92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100" orderby="rand"] Description The thirty-two storey resort condominium in Phuket, located Just 150m from Patong beach where choices of activities, water sp ';
$string = preg_replace('/\[gallery ids=[^\]]+\]/', '', $string);
```

Breakdown:

`\[gallery ids=` look for substring that begins with `[gallery ids=`

`[^\]]+\]` match 1 or more characters that are not `]` until you reach a `]`

Will then replace that whole matched portion with `''` nothing and you have your new string.

Comment: cryptic, This is what I'm talking about. Thank you. Problem solved.