# php: remove double square brackets and everything in between

Tags: php, preg-replace, square-bracket

From a variable, I want to remove double square brackets [[ ]] and everything in between, and then replace it with **img inserted**

I've got the following column result:

```
<p>hey</p><p>[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_large","fid":"67","attributes":{"alt":"","class":"media-image","height":"125","typeof":"foaf:Image","width":"125"}}]]</p>
```

After replace the variable should become:

```
<p>heey</p><p><b>img inserted<b></p>
```

I've tried to use preg_replace but this seems to be too advanced for me yet..

Can anyone give me some advice on how to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15187486/php-how-to-remove-string-between-and

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$string = '<p>hey</p><p>[[{"type":"media","view_mode":"media_large","fid":"67","attributes":{"alt":"","class":"media-image","height":"125","typeof":"foaf:Image","width":"125"}}]]</p>';
$new_string = preg_replace('/\[\[.*?\]\]/', '<b>img inserted</b>', $string);

echo $new_string;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<?PHP
    $subject = '<p>hey</p><p>[[{\"type\":\"media\",\"view_mode\":\"media_large\",\"fid\":\"67\",\"attributes\":{\"alt\":\"\",\"class\":\"media-image\",\"height\":\"125\",\"typeof\":\"foaf:Image\",\"width\":\"125\"}}]]</p>';
    $pattern = '/\[\[[^[]*]]/';
    $replace = '<b>img inserted</b>';
    $result = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject);
    echo '<p>Result: '.htmlspecialchars($result).'</p>';
?>
```

For your explanation: /.../ delimits the regular expression. The [[ has to be escaped, because [ is a special character, thus `\[\[`. After that, we get any character that is not a [ by using `[^[]`. This is repeated as often as needed: `[^[]*`. After that, we have two brackets: `\]\]`

Also, this will not work if within the square brackets there is a [. Judging from your format, this is not the case. Otherwise, you would have to use a more complicated syntax, most likely using back-references if those extra ['s are escaped ([). If unescaped brackets can occur, you cannot solve this with regular expressions.

Comment: Update your answer, instead of adding comments to it. I've updated them to your answer. Please remove your comments :)